# Delphi. How to Send a Thread a Message from a Form and for the Thread to Process the Message

Tags: multithreading, delphi

I have a Main Form that creates a Thread.

The Thread creates a Form with a Progress bar.

What I'm trying to do is create the Thread from the Main Form and send a message to the Thread to increase the Progress bar on the Thread Form.
This will allow me to execute code and provide the user with the progress.

So far I have the Main Form:-

```
unit uMain;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms, Dialogs, contnrs,
  StdCtrls, uThread, ExtCtrls;

type
  TMainForm = class(TForm)
    btnCreateForm: TButton;
    btnSendMessage: TButton;
    procedure btnCreateFormClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnSendMessageClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    MyProgressBarThread: TProgressBarThread;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  MainForm: TMainForm;

implementation

{$R *.DFM}

procedure TMainForm.btnCreateFormClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  MyProgressBarThread := TProgressBarThread.Create(Self);
end;

procedure TMainForm.btnSendMessageClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // Is this correct way to send a message to the Thread?
  PostThreadMessage(MyProgressBarThread.Handle, WM_USER, 0, 0);
end;

procedure TMainForm.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Assigned(MyProgressBarThread) then
    MyProgressBarThread.Terminate;
end;

end.
```

And the Thread:-

```
unit uThread;

interface

uses
  Forms, StdCtrls, Graphics, ExtCtrls, ClipBrd, Contnrs, JPeg, SysUtils,
  ComCtrls, System.Classes{taRightJustify}, Winapi.Messages, Winapi.Windows;

type
  TProgressBarThread = class(TThread)
  private
    { Private declarations }
    FForm: TForm;
    FUse_Progress_Position_Label: Boolean;
    lbProcessing_Name: TLabel;
    lbProcessing_Description: TLabel;
    lbProcessing_Position_Number: TLabel;
    ProgressBar1: TProgressBar;
    procedure OnCloseForm(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
    procedure OnDestroyForm(Sender: TObject);
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    constructor Create(AForm: TForm);
  end;

implementation

{ TProgressBarThread }
constructor TProgressBarThread.Create(AForm: TForm);
begin
  FForm := TForm.Create(nil);
  lbProcessing_Name := TLabel.Create(FForm);
  ProgressBar1 := TProgressBar.Create(FForm);
  lbProcessing_Description := TLabel.Create(FForm);
  lbProcessing_Position_Number := TLabel.Create(FForm);

  with FForm do
  begin
    Caption := 'Please Wait...';
    Left := 277;
    Top := 296;
    BorderIcons := [biSystemMenu];
    BorderStyle := bsSingle;
    ClientHeight := 80;
    ClientWidth := 476;
    Color := clBtnFace;
    Font.Color := clWindowText;
    Font.Height := -11;
    Font.Name := 'MS Sans Serif';
    Font.Style := [];
    FormStyle := fsStayOnTop;
    OldCreateOrder := False;
    Position := poMainFormCenter;
    PixelsPerInch := 96;
    OnClose := OnCloseForm;
    OnDestroy := OnDestroyForm;

    with lbProcessing_Name do
    begin
      Parent := FForm;
      Left := 16;
      Top := 24;
      Width := 130;
      Height := 13;
      Caption := 'Processing Request... ';
      Font.Color := clWindowText;
      Font.Height := -11;
      Font.Name := 'MS Sans Serif';
      Font.Style := [fsBold];
      ParentFont := False;
    end;

    with lbProcessing_Description do
    begin
      Parent := FForm;
      Left := 160;
      Top := 24;
      Width := 3;
      Height := 13;
      Font.Color := clBlue;
      Font.Height := -11;
      Font.Name := 'MS Sans Serif';
      Font.Style := [];
      ParentFont := False;
    end;

    with lbProcessing_Position_Number do
    begin
      Parent := FForm;
      Left := 456;
      Top := 24;
      Width := 6;
      Height := 13;
      Alignment := taRightJustify;
      Caption := '0';
      Visible := False;
      Font.Color := clBlue;
      Font.Height := -11;
      Font.Name := 'MS Sans Serif';
      Font.Style := [];
    end;

    with ProgressBar1 do
    begin
      Parent := FForm;
      Left := 16;
      Top := 48;
      Width := 449;
      Height := 17;
      TabOrder := 0;
    end;
  end;

  FForm.Show;

  inherited Create(False);
end;

procedure TProgressBarThread.Execute;
var
  Msg: TMsg;
begin
  FreeOnTerminate := True;
  // Is this the correct way to Look for Messages sent to the Thread and to handle them?
  while not (Terminated or Application.Terminated) do
  begin
    if PeekMessage(&Msg, 0, 0, 0, PM_NOREMOVE) then
    begin
      if Msg.message > 0 then
        ProgressBar1.Position := ProgressBar1.Position + 1;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TProgressBarThread.OnCloseForm(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  Terminate;
//  WaitFor;
end;

procedure TProgressBarThread.OnDestroyForm(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if not Terminated then
  begin
    Terminate;
    WaitFor;
  end;
end;

end.
```

1. Is this the correct way to go for my situation? If not then any examples?
2. Is the PostThreadMessage(MyProgressBarThread.Handle, WM_USER, 0, 0); correct?
3. How do I Listening for messages in the Thread and process them?

tia

Updated based on comments 09/07/2021
Is this code correct and safe:-
MainForm

```
unit uMain;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms, Dialogs, contnrs,
  StdCtrls, uThread, ExtCtrls;

type
  TMainForm = class(TForm)
    btnStart_Process: TButton;
    procedure btnStart_ProcessClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    Start_ProcessThread: TStart_ProcessThread;
    procedure TheCallback(const ProgressBarPosition: Integer);
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  MainForm: TMainForm;
  hLogWnd: HWND = 0;

implementation

uses
  uProgressBar;

{$R *.DFM}

procedure TMainForm.btnStart_ProcessClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  frmProgressBar.ProgressBar1.Max := Con_Max_ProgressBarPosition;
  frmProgressBar.ProgressBar1.Position := 0;
  frmProgressBar.Show;
  Start_ProcessThread := TStart_ProcessThread.Create(TheCallback);
end;

procedure TMainForm.TheCallback(const ProgressBarPosition: Integer);
begin
  if ProgressBarPosition <> Con_Finished_Processing then
    frmProgressBar.ProgressBar1.Position := ProgressBarPosition
  else
    frmProgressBar.Close;
end;

end.
```

ProgressBarForm

```
unit uProgressBar;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.ComCtrls;

type
  TfrmProgressBar = class(TForm)
    ProgressBar1: TProgressBar;
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  frmProgressBar: TfrmProgressBar;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

end.
```

Thread

```
unit uThread;

interface

uses
  Forms, StdCtrls, Graphics, ExtCtrls, ClipBrd, Contnrs, JPeg, SysUtils,
  ComCtrls, System.Classes{taRightJustify}, Winapi.Messages, Winapi.Windows;

const
  Con_Finished_Processing = -1;
  Con_Max_ProgressBarPosition = 1024 * 65536;

type
  TMyCallback = procedure(const ProgressBarPosition: Integer) of object;

  TStart_ProcessThread = class(TThread)
  private
    FCallback : TMyCallback;
    procedure Execute; override;
    procedure SendLog(I: Integer);
  public
    constructor Create(aCallback : TMyCallback);
  end;

implementation

{ TStart_ProcessThread }

constructor TStart_ProcessThread.Create(aCallback: TMyCallback);
begin
  inherited Create(false);
  FCallback := aCallback;
end;

procedure TStart_ProcessThread.SendLog(I: Integer);
begin
  if not Assigned(FCallback) then
    Exit;
  Self.Queue(  // Executed later in the main thread
    procedure
    begin
      FCallback(I{ThePosition});
    end
  );
end;

procedure TStart_ProcessThread.Execute;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  // Do the Work Load here:-
  for I := 0 to Con_Max_ProgressBarPosition do
  begin
    if ((I mod 65536) = 0) then
    begin
      // Send back the progress of the work here:-
      SendLog(I);
      Sleep(10);
    end;
  end;

  // Finished
  SendLog(Con_Finished_Processing);
end;

end.
```

Comment: Your form and progress logic is upside down. You don't need to send progress from the  form to the thread, you need to send progress from thread execute method to the form. Form needs to process progress message and set progress bar position. Setting progress bar position from the context of the background thread is not thread safe. You should never access UI controls from background threads. I am assuming that you are performing work in background thread. If you are doing work in main thread then updating progress from the thread is also wrong approach.

Comment: @Dalija Prasnikar. Thanks for the Reply. Main Form performs the work. Thread to display the progress. Displaying another standard form from the Main form with a progress bar to display the position doesn't always work, even with Application.ProcessMessages, Progress.Repaint etc. Any examples on what I'm trying to achieve? Thanks.

Comment: Move the lengthy task from the main thread to the secondary thread. And use `PostMessage` from the secondary thread to the main thread in order to update the UI.

Comment: If you do the work in the main thread, you will not be able to use thread to update progress. Main problem is that UI controls must be used from main thread and while main thread is working it cannot do anything else. This is where Application.ProcessMessages steps in and allows processing windows messages so you can update UI - including progress bar. But this is poor solution. Only proper solution is moving work to background thread. Depending on what you actually do (work) Application.ProcessMessages could possibly be patched, but this approach will always suffer from some problems.

Comment: You can find some code examples in https://github.com/dalijap/code-delphi-async Look at chapter 4 and 6, although others may be useful, too.

Comment: Just to add to the original question was was the aspect of reusability. i.e. Calling a Thread based Form with a progress bar on it and reuse for different scenarios. 

By moving the work load into the Thread breaks the reusability aspect.

Thanks again for the comments.

Comment: If you move work into background thread, you still have reusability because your progress form does not care what kind of work you are doing in the thread. You don't lose anything.

Comment: @Yuppski This is not something you want to make easy to re-use because it is the *wrong way* to write your software.  The thread should be doing the work and the Form should be managing the UI.  That's what the main thread's ONLY responsibility is - to manage the UI.  Don't load it up with work that prevents it from servicing the UI.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Based on the comments I have added some code to the main question under "Updated based on comments 09/07/2021 Is this code correct and safe" and would like to know if this is the correct and safe way. Thanks

Comment: @Yuppski Yes, that looks at least the right way around.  Putting a progress bar into a thread is a bit like driving a transport truck and putting all the cargo in the driver's seat...then inventing a Mr. Bean contraption to access the pedals and steering wheel with ropes, pulleys, and levers that go all the way to the cargo area at the back... where you've bolted a chair to the empty box of your truck.

Answer (score 1):

If your going for additional Components: i would suggest looking at **Omni Thread Library**.

http://www.omnithreadlibrary.com/book/chap10.html#leanpub-auto-sending-data-from-a-worker-to-a-form
The 7.13.2 Example in the current Version (Sending data from a worker to a form)

Its a great Library and the free book from the link above is a good source for many multithreaded Scenarios.

I use almost every Time the **3.2 Blocking collection** (in the text there is a link to the demo source) Its not specially what your looking for, but a combination of both should be powerfull to create multihreaded chains of workloads.

Answer (score -1):

kbmMW contains a feature called SmartEvent which I would recommend checking out. It works great in such scenarios, where you want different parts of your code (threaded or not) to communicate with each other and transfer data.

It works as simple as this:

```
TForm1 = class(...)
...
private
   procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
public
   [kbmMW_Event('UPDATESTATUS',[mweoSync])]
   procedure UpdateStatus(const APct:integer);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
    Event.Subscribe(self);
end;

procedure TForm1.UpdateStatus(const APct:integer);
begin
    Label1.Caption:='Pct='+inttostr(APct);
end;
```

and then in your thread do:

```
procedure TYourThread.Execute;
begin
    ...
    Event.Notify('UPDATESTATUS',pct);
    ...
end;
```

All thread synchronization etc. will be handled automatically for you.
You can even make calls, expecting data back, and there can be any number of subscribers for your notifications.

kbmMW is a toolbox that fully supports Delphi and all platforms.

You can read more about SmartEvent here: https://components4developers.blog/2019/11/11/smartevent-with-kbmmw-1/